# Spring randomly seems to lose a bean?

Tags: java, spring, long-polling

I have strange problem.

status is class level instance of EndpointStatus ( no job given in constructor )

```
private EndpointStatus status = new EndpointStatus(1L, EndpointStatus.Status.AVAILABLE);

....omitted....

@POST
@Path("/calculated")
public Response reCalculated(String req,
                         final @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {

   if ( status.isBusy() ) { return Response.ok( status.getCurrentJob() ).build(); }
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        status.setStatus(EndpointStatus.Status.BUSY);

        CurrentJob job = new CurrentJob();
        job.setId(1L);
        job.setJobStatus("ACTIVE");
        job.setJobId(uuid);
        status.setCurrentJob(job);

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                thymeNewDateRange.getDataForDateRange(thymeDate, null, status);
                status.setCurrentJob(null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                serverLogger.error(e);
            }
        });
        return Response.accepted(job).build();
}
```

**So here i receive a POST**

1. status changes from AVAILABLE -> BUSY
2. create a job obj with generated UUID.
3. Then job object is set into status obj.
4. return 202 immediately with UUID (Long running job)

Return from initial post: ( job class )

```
{
"id" : 1,
"jobId" : "5d974c2d-e01a-4842-ad5f-1ef7d78901c0",
"jobStatus" : "ACTIVE",
}
```

everything here is fine. Client has started to query 5d974c2d-e01a-4842-ad5f-1ef7d78901c0 as a url instead, and gets the same JSON back as long as the results are not ready.

but but

shortly after first few queries ( before this SO post, client ran for 3 queries, before that it was 5, so random )

```
status.setCurrentJob(null);
```

will seemingly be called ( is below long running job in POST method )
This will return endpoint from BUSY to AVAILABLE, even if the job is just started and will take hours to complete.

After setting null job endpoint will respond with: ( status class returned since currentJob is set to null )

```
{
"id" : 1,
"status" : "AVAILABLE",
"currentJob" : null,
"busy" : false
 }
```

Which will in turn stop querying from client and so client loses all the data..

Shouldn't

```
 status.setCurrentJob(null);
```

be called just after

```
thymeNewDateRange.getDataForDateRange(thymeDate, null, status);
```

has completed? This is the only instance of setting job to null, in the whole app, so it should propagate from here?

endpoint for querying job

```
@GET
@Path("/job")
public Response queryJob(@Context SecurityContext securityContext,
                          @QueryParam("pid") String pid) {

    if( status.getCurrentJob() != null ) {
        return Response.ok(status.getCurrentJob()).build();

    }
    if( status.getStatus() == EndpointStatus.Status.AVAILABLE ) {
        //JOB HAS ENDED - but this will still trigger too early
        return Response.ok(status).build();
    }else {
        return Response.ok("ERROR STATE").build();
    }


}
```

Please feel free to ask anything i forgot to mention.. this is kind of a long and complicated post.

Cheers ;)

**EDIT** oookey, i need help or an exorcist...

tried with volatile ( thanks @paulturnip ) but it didnt help

**furthermore** the problem seems to ONLY persist on the "real" test server.
While run locally with localhost:8080 this problem never comes up...

but when run on the server this just keeps happening.

i added logger as a first line in @Path("/job") to log:

```
serverLogger.info("STATUS: " + status.getStatus().toString() + " JOB STATUS: " + status.getCurrentJob().getJobStatus() );
```

And locally, once again there is no nullPointer. But as soon as ran on proper server enviroment, somehow `status.getCurrentJob().getJobStatus()` will throw NullPointerException, even tho

```
CurrentJob job = new CurrentJob();
        job.setId(1L);
        job.setJobStatus("ACTIVE");
        job.setJobId(uuid);

        status.setCurrentJob(job);
```

is set, literally one call before ( /calculated )

**EDIT2:**

CurrentJob bean:

```
@Entity
public class CurrentJob {

@Id
private Long id;
private volatile String jobId;
private volatile String jobStatus;

.... basic getter&setter&constructor ....
```

Im using hibernate, so @Entity and @Id, but i since i was not planning to save this instance, i was wondering if these could someway interfere with state?

Comment: I would mark your status as `volatile` or use an `AtomicReference`

Comment: Thank you @paulturnip i'll look into that now!

Comment: you don't look like you are checking to see if the status is already busy before you start a new job. is this intended? if so then every new job submission has a chance of setting the status current job to null  when it eventually completes in the other thread

Comment: many thanks to you! That seem like a logical solution.. but unfortunately i had the "if" there.. it just somehow got dropped between edits.. sorry about that.. Edited it back now.. thank you anyways. @David